# Can't get DBD::ODBC to work with DataDirect ODBC Driver Manager 7.0 - [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded (SQL-IM003)

Tags: perl, odbc, solaris, informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to set-up PERL DBD::ODBC to use the DataDirect ODBC Driver Manager (7.0) that is provided with Informatica PowerCenter.  This is on a Solaris 10 Sparc64 environment.  We've had this working in the past with the 5.1 driver manager (on an sp32 server), but now running into problems since moving to this new version.  For all ODBC connections I get this error:

```
failed: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded (SQL-IM003) at test_odbctd.pl line 19
Can't connect to DBI:ODBC:tdedwprd: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded (SQL-IM003) at test_odbctd.pl line 19, <STDIN> line 2.
```

I have tested the same connections using the "ssgodbc" tool provided by Informatica for testing and they work.  I can login and run queries.

As an example, here's one of my Teradata connections as definied in odbc.ini (we're having the same problem with DB2, SQL Server, Teradata, Sybase, PowerExchange, etc).  *Don't ask why I have to hard-code the full driver path in this file instead of odbcinst.ini.  I couldn't get it to work and the Informatica standard is to hard-code it in odbc.ini so I don't want to affect our support from them.*

```
[tddev]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers/tdata.so
Description=Teradata Development
DBCName=teradata1
DBCName2=teradata2
MaxRespSize=65477
DateTimeFormat=AAA
EnableExtendedStmtInfo=No
LoginTimeout=60
```

ldd output for the driver:

```
$ ldd /opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers/tdata.so
warning: ldd: /opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers/tdata.so: is not executable
        libCstd.so.1 =>  /opt/SUNWspro/lib/v9/libCstd.so.1
        libthread.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/sparcv9/libthread.so.1
        libm.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/sparcv9/libm.so.1
        libw.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/sparcv9/libw.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/sparcv9/libc.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/sparcv9/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/sparcv9/libnsl.so.1
        libxnet.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/sparcv9/libxnet.so.1
        libodbcinst.so =>        /opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/lib/libodbcinst.so
        libddicu25.so =>         /opt/teradata/client/odbc/lib/libddicu25.so
        libtdparse.so =>         /opt/teradata/client/odbc/lib/libtdparse.so
        libicudatatd.so.46 =>    /usr/lib/sparcv9/libicudatatd.so.46
        libicuuctd.so.46 =>      /usr/lib/sparcv9/libicuuctd.so.46
        libCrun.so.1 =>  /opt/SUNWspro/prod/usr/lib/v9/libCrun.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/64/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/64/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libscf.so.1
        libDWicu26.so =>         /opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/lib/libDWicu26.so
        libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/sparcv9/libdl.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/sparcv9/librt.so.1
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/sparcv9/libpthread.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/64/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/64/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libgen.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/64/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/64/libm.so.2
        /lib/sparcv9/../libm/sparcv9/libm_hwcap1.so.2
        /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libmd_psr.so.1
```

I tried to run strace as the user that uses these connections, but I get this error so not sure what to do with that:

```
$ strace perl test_odbctd.pl
ERROR: unable to open /dev/log
```

Here's the PERL test script we're using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
# use DBD::ODBC;
# use DBD::DB2::Constants;


my $data_source = "DBI:ODBC:tdedwprd";

#Prompt for username
print "Enter user:";
my $user = <STDIN>;

#Prompt for password
print "Enter password:";
my $password =<STDIN>;

# Connect to the tdedwdev teradata database
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $password, {AutoCommit =>1})
                or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";
$stmt = "SELECT database, time; ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute();

#associate variable with output columns...

$sth->bind_col(1,\$db);
$sth->bind_col(2,\$timestap);
while ($sth->fetch) {
           print "The database is: $db\n";
           print "The time is: $timestap\n";
}
$dbh->disconnect;
```

The above script works on our existing dev box (Solaris 10 sp32), but not on the new one we're building (Solaris 10 sp64).

The old server had the driver manager bundled with Informatica PowerCenter 8.6.1 sp32, and the new one has Informatica PowerCenter 9.5.1 sp64.

The DBD::ODBC module did compile fine with some modifications, roughly following this guide from DataDirect (the logic was basically the same, but the references to the Makefile.PL weren't identical):

http://knowledgebase.datadirect.com/articles/Article/2973

I enabled Trace in odbc.ini (Trace=1) but this just resulted in a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)".  However it does output a trace file when using the Informatica-provided "ssgodbc" tool.

I tried using isql, but it seems to be tied to the Sybase drivers so I'm not sure if I can use that.  I couldn't get it to work

```
$ which isql
/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/bin/isql
```

Here are my ODBC environment variables:

```
$ env | grep -i odbc
MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_32/help/man:
ODBCINST=/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/odbcinst.ini
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/lib:/opt/powercenter/v951/server/bin:/home/etlin1d/sqllib/lib:/opt/pwx/v851:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p64:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/lib:/opt/teradata/client/odbc/lib:/opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/lib:/usr/lib:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/lib64:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/lib32:/usr/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/lib:/opt/powercenter/v951/server/bin:/opt/pwx/v851:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/lib64:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p64:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/lib3p:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/lib:/opt/teradata/client/odbc/lib:/opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers:/usr/lib
NLSPATH=/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/msg:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_32/msg:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/msg/%N:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/msg/%N:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_32/msg/%N:
PATH=/opt/sybase/ASEP/bin:/opt/sybase/DBISQL/bin:/opt/sybase/UAF-2_0/bin:/opt/sybase/OCS-15_0/bin:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/bin:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/tbuild/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/powercenter/v951/server/bin:.:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/bin:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/adm:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/misc:/prj/db2/etlin1d/sqllib/db2tss/bin
ODBCINI=/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0/odbc.ini
ODBCHOME=/opt/powercenter/v951/ODBC7.0
```

I'm totally at a loss.  I'm not a Solaris admin by trade though (in fact this is my first significant exposure to Solaris and Informatica really) so I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

I'm not sure what else to share right now.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  I've been stuck on problems with this ODBC implementation for weeks.

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you ask DataDirect? It is their driver and instructions you have followed.

Comment: Because the DataDirect software is provided by Informatica, we don't have a support contract with DataDirect.  Informatica won't help us because they don't support PERL.

Comment: The error "[DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded" is coming from DataDirect so your problem lies there and not in DBD::ODBC as far as I can see. The evidence I have for this is that as the error comes from DD, then DBD::ODBC must have successfully loaded the driver manager.

Comment: Thanks bohica.  The thing that is confusing me is that I can use a different tool under the same account using the same driver manager, and it works.  Only with DBD::ODBC does it fail.  Is there something there that would be affecting environment variables, or something the Perl module can't see?

Comment: I'm sorry but your using proprietary code I cannot see or get hold of and the license for the software you are using is rather restrictive. I can tell you I know people who have used the unixODBC driver manager and a teradata ODBC driver. I've heard the DD driver manager has a load of extra environment and connection handle attributes that are not in ODBC that DBD::ODBC won't know about but I'm only guessing this could cause an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem here was not with the driver manager.  It was caused by the fact that I was using 32-bit Perl but a 64-bit ODBC driver.  If I added an entry that used a 32-bit ODBC driver to `odbc.ini` (despite the driver manager being 64-bit) then there is no problem (although it did raise a licensing issue which is separate to this discussion).

In short, this error message occured because the driver is not the same *bitness* as the client (check by running the `file` command against both client and driver):

```
 Specified driver could not be loaded
```

An example of the `file` command is:

```
 file /opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers/tdata.so
```

However, it also occurs when the driver cannot find all of its dependent drivers, which can be checked using `ldd` on the driver to make sure it is finding all of its dependencies.

An example of the `ldd` command is:

```
 ldd /opt/teradata/client/odbc/drivers/tdata.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above method given by LokMac, all dependant drivers were there and still it wont work, at the end I added "# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to." before driver path and it magically worked:

```
[tddemo] 
# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to.
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
```

in above, tddemo is my DNS name and since I am on TD Express 16.20, thats why my driver name is different.